# write() syscall on LUKS partition

Tags: operating-system, fsync, luks

To my understanding, when the [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite) syscall is called, it writes the data to the OS buffer then returns.
My question, on LUKS partitions, are:

1. Does [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite) encrypt data then write to OS buffer then returns? OR, it just writes the raw data then returns, and only when the OS flushes its buffer to disk is the data encrypted?
2. What if after calling [`write()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/pwrite), [`fsync()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) is also called?

How can I verify the exact behavior?
I have been searching on Google but no result thus far.

Comment: At a guess (2), as LUKS presents a block device to the OS.